# A form link in a document - Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

A document is where you can view the details .
And a form is something like a document where you can put inputs, choose whatever you want in a dropdown, fill up textfields and etc.

- How can I put a link that will redirect to a form, and can be filled up?
- Do I need to use appendDocLink?

  And I'm very new to Domino Designer, please bear with me.

Comment: Do you want the link to open a form in order to load the values from the current document so you can edit them? Or  do you want the link to open the form so that you can create a new, unrelated document?

Comment: I want the link to open the form so that I can create a new document. That's what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Button, Action, or hotspot to your form, and give it a formula like this:

```
@Command[Compose];"": ""; "TheNameOfYourFormGoesHere");
```

You can find the syntax of the Compose command [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/bb56a4a7ca9db78385256c54004c1cf5?OpenDocument).

Answer (score 1):

I recommand not explaining what a form or a document is, but only ask you question...

In order to responde to your question tel us "where you want to put a link" (web / notes client ?)
You don't need appendDoclink.

Look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/ you can make a (web) link to "redirect" user to create a new document = fill a form : http://Host/Database/FormName?OpenForm

Comment: I want the link in the notes client.